# react-select, options are not rendering, besides for first one, but it's not visible? and when it goes to my onSelectOption the whole array is going

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am getting an array of flavors from my backend.

This is my jsx:

```
<div className="mb-3">         
<Select options={flavorOptions} onChange={onSelectOption} value={flavor} />
</div>
```

The array is being formatted to the correct format needed for react-select, like this:

```
const flavorOptions =
        [
            flavors.map(f => {                
                return {
                    value: f, label: f
                }
            })
        ]
```

This is my onSelectOption function:

```
const onSelectOption = (option) => {
        const copy = {...order}
        copy.flavor = option.value
        setOrder(copy)
    }
```

This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y7Tv.png)

and when I click on that one option (that isn't even visible), the first option shows up but when onChange calls the onSelectOption function the whole array gets sent in.

So really my question has three parts:

1. Why is only one option showing up?
2. Why isn't it visible?
3. Why is the whole array getting passed to the onSelectOption function, as opposed to just the selected value?

I tried adding these props - `getOptionLabel={option => option.label} getOptionValue={option => option.value}` to Select and got the same results.
I also tried this:

```
<Select>
   {flavorOptions.map(flavor => {
       <option key={flavor.label} value={flavor.value} > {flavor.label}</option>
   })}
</Select>
```

which resulted in getting the No options message.

If anyone has any idea what I might be doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate feedback.
I am very new to react, and programming in general so it could very well be a careless mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the square brackets here:

```js
const flavorOptions =
            flavors.map(f => {                
                return {
                    value: f, label: f
                }
            })
```

What you passed in was like `[["apple", "banana"]]` when you just need `["apple", "banana"]`

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wrswve?file=src%2FApp.tsx